# How to send encode string as a parameter into url string in angular and open in new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

How to send encode string as a parameter into URL string in angular and open in new tab. I am trying to send multiple parameter separated by '-' and converted into base64 encode through url but it is throwing me into not found. I am using angular 8. using router.navigate , it is working fine but I want to open url in new tab.

here is my code in TS.

```
 goToAssessmentPage(event, assignmentId, courseId, studentId, instituteId, sectionId , assignment_submission_id) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const string:string = btoa(courseId + '-' + assignmentId + '-' + studentId + '-' + instituteId + '-' + sectionId + '-' + assignment_submission_id)
    const url: string = string + '/grader-assessment';
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
```

app.routing.ts

```
{
    path: ':params/grader-assessment',
    component: GraderAssessmentPageComponent
},
```

Comment: did you try to put the url in <a> with router link and target _blank?

Comment: @BrunoCerecetto - That would be a nice solution too if it can be used in his case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you'll more than likely need the whole url tree in that url string for window.open to work.

From the docs (https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createurltree)

```
// create /team/33/user/11
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, 'user', 11]);
```

And on top of that (https://angular.io/api/router/Router#serializeurl)

serializeUrl(url: UrlTree): string

So in your case it would be something like:

```
const string:string = btoa(courseId + '-' + assignmentId + '-' + studentId + '-' + instituteId + '-' + sectionId + '-' + assignment_submission_id)
const fullUrl:string = this.router.serializeUrl(router.createUrlTree([string, '/grader-assessment']));
// Then you navigate to this full url
window.open(fullUrl, '_blank');
```

Comment: this is perfect way of openingURL in new tab in angular  with parameters sent in encoded manner.